# Rest error handling

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am exposing lot of serives via REST Jersey.I have somehting like this

```
     @Provider

     public class CatchAll implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> 
        {
         @Override
            public Response toResponse(Throwable th) {
                return ExceptionHandler.handleException(th);
            }
        }

        public class ExceptionHandler {

          public static Response handleException(Throwable e) {
         if (e instanceof x) {
                  //   handlex

                    } else if(e instanceof Y)  {
                       //handley

                    } else if( e instanceof Z) {
                        //handle z
                    } else if{
               }

                elseif {
           }


        }
}
```

Th problem with this approach is maintaining the code  every time when i add new exception or new service I have to add if else.Can any one suggest Any better way to handle  the Rest exception

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an ExceptionMapper for every application exception you need.

```
@Provider
public class MyApplicationExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<MyApplicationException> {
// ...
}
```

For more information see https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e5206